# What do I do when I reset a device and it says I have to sign in with a Google account that was previously synced on this device it's Alcatel Pixi 4

Tags: sync

Help
Please help me I bought this phone from a friend and I factory reset it and this is what shows up

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I trust you don't want the sync'd data.  If so, then start over and don't give it your email address.  Or create a new gmail address and use that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought the phone off a friend, bring it back to him and tell him to sign in and then delete his account after he signed in.

However, you could try going into recovery mode and wiping the phone from there.